# Cant get a curved line in my logistic regression model

Tags: r, logistic-regression

I keep getting a straight line instead of a curved line .. ): 
Here is my code (I have 2 rows of data):

```
mymodel <- glm(row3 ~ row1 + row2, data=data, family="binomial")
confmatrix <- table(Actual_value=data$row3, Predicted_value = res > 0.5 )

Coefficients:
              Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept)  5.528e-05  8.096e-02   0.001    0.999    
row1         2.054e+00  1.601e-01  12.830   <2e-16 ***
row2        -2.357e+00  1.692e-01 -13.932   <2e-16 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

plot(row3 ~ row1 + row2, data=data, col="red4")

> range(data$row1)
[1] -0.9950269  0.9970726
> range(data$row2)
[1] -0.9987826  0.9974060

> xv <- seq(min(data$row1), max(data$row1), 0.01)
> yv <- predict(mymodel, list(row1=xv, row2=xv), type="response")
> lines(xv, yv, col="blue")
```

this gives me a straight line as a output but i want the line to be curved,
what am i doing wrong ?

```
data:
> dput(data[1:10, ])
structure(list(row1 = c(-0.228244850627602, -0.579118049124784, 
-0.83833242721105, 0.331746035028978, 0.265438414881288, -0.291282866857274, 
-0.217044905717291, 0.125016813138315, 0.965216795695969, 0.0659191928502751
), row2 = c(-0.857870264293455, -0.34716207447565, 0.865458604130724, 
0.447644706745721, -0.0719620361325586, 0.153072010992213, 
-0.677216788715359, 
-0.411643123725395, -0.697268680602617, -0.155335060339782), 
row3 = c(1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0)), row.names = c(NA, 
10L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: thankyou, but sadly that doesnt solve the problem ):

Comment: You define `xv` after `yv` which is defined with `xv`... Something wrong here. Also, please provide a full code so that we can reproduce.

Comment: @StupidWolf mymodel <- glm(row3 ~ row1 + row2, data=data, family="binomial")

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent updated the code

Comment: ... and provide `data` please (`dput(data)`).

Comment: To get a prediction curve for the probability of `row3` as a function of `row1`, you need to generate predicted `row3` for several values of `row1`, *with `row2` held constant at a single value*. (And you can of course do this for several different values of `row 2` to get several curves for `row3` vs. `row1`, each for a different single value of `row2`.)

Comment: @eipi10 is correct, looking at your coefficients, if you provide the same value for row1 and row2, they will cancel out each other. Which is why you see a flat line. You need to either set one to 0 and have different values

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent the data is 1000 lines haha its a bit much to post i think
EDIT: its added to the code

Comment: Then, for example, do `dput(data[1:20, ])` to provide the first 20 rows.

Comment: @eipi10  have no clue how to do that, which line do i need to change

Comment: Example: `yv <- predict(mymodel, newdata=data.frame(row1=xv, row2=median(data$row2, na.rm=TRUE)), type="response")`. This will give you predictions (as probabilities) of `row3` as a function of `row1` when `row2` is held constant at its median value.

Comment: @eipi10 aaah thankyou its looking a lot less straight right now! its working